# How can I create aliases of objects that inherit only a particular attribute

Tags: python-3.x, object, alias

I'm making a program in python where the user can add a name and number to a list.
I went with saving the entries in a class with 2 attributes and saving the instances of the class as objects in a list:

```
class NewEntry:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.number = ""

entry = NewEntry()
entry.name = userinput[1]
entry.number = userinput[2]

entrylist.append(entry)
```

I'm now trying to add a function called alias, that will save an entry under a new name. The alias is supposed to be connected to the original entry in such a way that changing the number of one of them will change the number of every corresponding alias to the same value.
Here is the code for my attempt at this:

```
for key in entrylist:
    if key.name == userinput[1]:
        entry = key
        entry.name = userinput[2]
        entrylist.append(entry)
```

This does not work as intended. When creating a new alias, it also changes the .name of key, the I'm attempting to only inherit the number-attribute from.

I've also attempted the following method:

```
for key in entrylist:
    if key.name == userinput[1]:
        entry = NewEntry()
        entry.name = userinput[2]
        entry.number = key.number
        entrylist.append(entry)
```

TL;DR:
I want to be able to create copies of an object where the .number-attribute is the same across all aliases. I want the name to be different in all of these objects, but the number to stay the same. A change in the number of one of the aliases would affect the others as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could link them up by adding an `alias_of` attribute to signify what a name is an alias of.

If you pair it up with a `property` for your `number` attribute then you control which object actually gets set.

```
class NewEntry:
    # I added the attributes as constructor
    # arguments since you're setting them anyway
    def __init__(self, name='', number=None, alias_of=None):
        self.name = name
        # since we want self.number to be a property
        # it is common practice to use a _ to signify
        # that an attribute is private
        self._number = number
        # here alias will refer to the instance it's
        # an alias of. It defaults to None
        # or not an alias
        self.alias_of = alias_of
    
    # giving a method a @property decorator
    # makes it get the attribute from here
    # That way you control which number it's getting
    @property
    def number(self):
        if self.alias_of:
            return self.alias_of.number
        else:
            return self._number
    
    # The same is true if you give it a setter
    # method. It controls which instances number
    # that you set
    @number.setter
    def number(self, value):
        if self.alias_of:
            self.alias_of.number = value
        else:
            self._number = value


entry = NewEntry('my name', number=1)
entry2 = NewEntry('my name 2', number=2)
# here we say that entry3 is an alias of entry
entry3 = NewEntry('my other name', alias_of=entry)

print(entry.number)
print(entry2.number)
# and here entry3 is actually setting entry
# 1's number attribute
entry3.number = 3
print(entry.number)
```